# Пропадет ли встроенная функция pow() при импорте одноименной функции из библиотеки math?

Tags: python, импорт

Если импортировать `math.pow()` с помощью кода
`from math import pow`
то я больше не смогу обращаться ко встроенной функции `pow()`?

Comment: `from builtins import pow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, при импорте `from math import pow` стандартная функция будет перекрыта. Это причина, почему не следует злоупотреблять импортом в глобальное пространство имен.

Если нельзя, но очень хочется:

```
>>> old_pow=pow
>>> from math import pow
>>> print( old_pow(10, 2, 3) )
1
```

или

```
>>> from math import pow
...
>>> from builtins import pow as old_pow
>>> print( old_pow(10, 2, 3) )
1
```

Comment: Проще использовать конструкцию ```from math import pow as new_pow```, верно?

Comment: @max думаю, вы правы

Answer (score 1):

Cможете, это разные функции. Чтобы в этом убедиться можно передать в нее три аргумента

```
print(pow(10, 2, 3))
```

Результат: `1`

```
import math
print(math.pow(10, 2, 3))
```

Результат: `TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 3`

При таком импорте функции: `from math import pow` она переопределится

```
print(pow.__doc__)
```

Результат: `Return x**y (x to the power of y)`

Comment: Вопрос стоял в использовании `from math import pow`

Comment: @Acinit, спасибо за замечание, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Из комментария @andreymal вывел интересную штуку.
Вы можете использовать `pow` как из встроенного в python модуля, так и из `math`

```
from math import pow
from builtins import pow as pow2 

print(pow2(10,2,3))
print(pow(10,2,3))
```

Вывод в консоли

```
1
```

А далее ошибка

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
pow expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @max Добро пожаловать на ruSO!